# Move CSS Thumbnail Border

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Here is a screenshot of a thumbnail grid. I want to move the gray border to be below the price and aligned consistently across all products. For example, the first product has a short title so the price appears on line 2. For the second product, price appears on line 3. I want the border below line 3 for all products.

[image]

Here is my html.erb

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail" > 
         <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive aspect"), listing %>
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
        <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
      </div>    
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css: Note that when I move the `border-bottom` from the thumbnail class to the caption class, the borders don't align consistently due to the variation in the length of product titles.

```
.thumbnail
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding: 80% 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

img
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.caption {

  h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 2px;
  }

  p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  }

position: relative;
top: -10px;

}
```

Comment: You have to move border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; to the .caption rule and add a min-height to be always positioned to the same place.

Comment: That works on desktop but it's not responsive. Can the 80px be represented differently so it's responsive?

Comment: Fixed heights will not work on responsive layouts. This solution is the easy way out and amateur.

Comment: You could calculate the div height with jquery and set it dynamically according to the higher one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate height of each container after loading the DOM, then adjust height of every container based on the height of the tallest object. The only way to acheive this is with JS.

Here's a useful plugin: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

I don't recommend setting a fixed height. This limits you if you are not using a fixed width layout and is the easy way out. It also is not professional in my opinion.